# What is this connector near a 2000 Durango SUV tow hitch?

Tags: dodge, wiring, connector, durango, wiring-harness

My 2000 Dodge Durango SUV has a 4-pin trailer light connector next to the towing hitch. Nearby, tucked up near the exposed spare tire, is this cable:

[image]

Looks like two contacts, although there may be a third contact recessed in the center.

Does anyone recognize it?

Comment: It may have been there for options not on your vehicle, so is likely not important.  Does the vehicle have reverse sensors?

Comment: I thought it might be a connection for an electric trailer brake, but have been unable to locate matching images.

Comment: No reverse sensors. I, too, was hoping it would be trailer brakes, but it turns out I don't have the factory-installed optional Towing Package. I'm going to have to add an after-market trailer brake controller. If I'm lucky, this might be a wiring harness to be used by a brake controller, and so would make my installation easier...

Comment: Did you check to see if it goes to the license plate light? This is a low amperage connection judging by the size/shape, so couldn't be for much more than a light bulb.